# bounds and frames: how do I display part of an UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

My goal is simple; I want to create a program that displays an UIImage, and when swiped from bottom to top, displays another UIImage. The images here could be a happy face/sad face. The sad face should be the starting point, the happy face the end point. When swiping your finger the part below the finger should be showing the happy face.

So far I tried solving this with the frame and bounds properties of the UIImageview I used for the happy face image.

What this piece of code does is wrong, because the transition starts in the center of the screen and not the bottom. Notice that the origin of both frame and bounds are at 0,0...

I have read numerous pages about frames and bounds, but I don't get it. Any help is appreciated!

The loadimages is called only once.

```
- (void)loadImages {
    sadface = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face-sad.jpg"];
    happyface = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face-happy.jpg"];
    UIImageView *face1view = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    face1view.image = sadface;
    [self.view addSubview:face1view];

    CGRect frame;
    CGRect contentRect = self.view.frame;
    frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentRect.size.width, contentRect.size.height);
    face1view.frame = frame;
    face2view = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    face2view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    face2view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    face2view.image = happyface;
    [self.view addSubview:face2view];
    frame = CGRectMake(startpoint.x, 0, contentRect.size.width, contentRect.size.height);
    face2view.frame = frame;
    face2view.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint movepoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView: self.view];
    NSLog(@"movepoint: %f %f", movepoint.x, movepoint.y);
    face2view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480 - movepoint.y);
}
```

The UIImages and UIImageViews are properly disposed of in the dealloc function.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you seem to be confused about frames and bounds. In fact, they are easy. Always remember that any view has its own coordinate system. The frame, center and transform properties are expressed in superview's coordinates, while the bounds is expressed in the view's own coordinate system. If a view doesn't have a superview (not installed into a view hierarchy yet), it still has a frame. In iOS the frame property is calculated from the view's bounds, center and transform. You may ask what the hell frame and center mean when there's no superview. They are used when you add the view to another view, allowing to position the view before it's actually visible.

The most common example when a view's bounds differ from its frame is when it is not in the upper left corner of its superview: its bounds.origin may be CGPointZero, while its frame.origin is not. Another classic example is UIScrollView, which frequently modifies its bounds.origin to make subviews scroll (in fact, modifying the origin of the coordinate system automatically moves every subview without affecting their frames), while its own frame is constant.

Back to your code. First of all, when you already have images to display in image views, it makes sense to init the views with their images:

```
UIImageView *face1view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: sadface];
```

That helps the image view to immediately size itself properly. It is not recommended to init views with `-init` because that might skip some important code in their designated initializer, `-initWithFrame:`.

Since you add face1view to self.view, you should really use its bounds rather than its frame:

```
face1view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

Same goes for the happier face. Then in `-touchesMoved:…` you should either change face2view's *frame* to move it inside self.view or (if self.view does not contain any other subviews besides faces) modify self.view's *bounds* to move both faces inside it together. Instead, you do something weird like vertically stretching the happy face inside face2view. If you want the happy face to slide from the bottom of self.view, you should initially set its frame like this (not visible initially):

```
face2view.frame = CGRectOffset(face2view.frame, 0, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds));
```

If you choose to swap faces by changing image views' frames (contrasted with changing self.view's *bounds*), I guess you might want to change both the views' frame origins, so that the sad face slides up out and the happy face slides up in. Alternatively, if you want the happy face to cover the sad one:

```
face2view.frame = face1view.frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to have something to do with the face2view.bounds in touchesMoved.
You are setting the bounds of this view to the rect, x:0, y:0, width:320, height:480 - y

x = 0 == left on the x axis

y = 0 == top on the y axis

So you are putting this image frame at the upper left corner, and making it fill the whole view. That's not what you want. The image simply becomes centered in this imageView.

Comment: I think I need to put the image frame at the top left corner. This is because the images must overlap (they are the same images, so if I put it at any other place, the happy face moves in respect to the sad face). Is there a way to show the happy face, starting at the bottom?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, could you describe it in a different way?

Comment: The images should be on top of eachother. Because the images are mostly the same, except for a smiling mouth and a sad mouth. When the transition takes place, the whole images should stay in one place. It looks like only the mouth changed from sad to happy. In order to get this, both images should start at 0,0. This means both images have a frame from 0,0 to 320,480